# custom property in LRS & Tincan API

Tags: drupal-7, tin-can-api, lrs

is it possible to add custom property to "Actor" via Tincan API to save it
in LRS.

Detail:
i am using Learning Locker as LRS system & Tincan API of Drupal & as its known there are 3 object inside the statement record that is saved in LRS which are [Actor - Verb - Object]
now the Actor has 2 properties which are [name - mbox] 
and i tried to modify the Tincan module to add custom property which is [country] but the LRS API "Learning Locker" refused it.
so is there a custom way to additional properties so that i can filter with later like [age - gender - country] or its standard API strict on the defined attributes

```
{
"version": "1.0.0",
"actor": {
    "objectType": "Agent",
    "name": "Creative User",
    "mbox": "mailto:register@example.com"
},
"verb": {
    "id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/action_custom_verb",
    "display": {
        "en-US": "action_custom_verb"
    }
},
"object": {
    "objectType": "Activity",
    "id": "http://localhost",
    "definition": {
        "name": {
            "en-US": "master"
        }
    }
},
"authority": {
    "objectType": "Agent",
    "name": "drupaladmin",
    "mbox": "mailto:hello@learninglocker.net"
},
"stored": "2017-02-06T16:58:23.625600+00:00",
"timestamp": "2017-02-06T16:58:23.625600+00:00",
"id": "9c1d552b-c825-4403-9c89-a9381b8d5320"
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard API is strict with respect to the addition of properties. And the Agent/Group objects (which are what `actor` can contain) do not include the ability to expand their scope.

Additional data points can be added in special properties called `extensions` that are available in a couple of places in the statement's objects. In this case you could use extensions in the `context` property's value to include your additional information about the `actor`. You could do this as single discrete pieces of information where each has its own extensions key, or you could use a single key that uses an object as its value and include individual pieces of information in properties of that object. For more information about extensions see: http://tincanapi.com/deep-dive-extensions/

Note that extensions keys are not filterable via the `/statements` stream resource, so any querying based off of their key or value will have to be done through other means than the specification's API.

Comment: what i specifically meant is to be able to property like "age" , "country"
which i know its not LRS standards, and after long investigation i figured that there is now way to do that, so if you know tweak around solution
would you show me example code or a reference link for example of what i need.
Thanks Brian.